# where did all the templates in xcode go?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0

After the recent update in xcode I seem to have lost all the template for cocoa touch and iphone templates. Under Cocoa Touch Classes in the new file dialog, I only have 3 choices:

Objective-C class
Objective-C test case class 
and UIViewController subclass

where did the others go? UITableView, UInavigation etc.?

I am running xcode 3.1.3. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

They are now in a drop down menu in that window. It defaults to subclass of NSObject, just select the one that you want from the menu and you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks, I saw that but if I remember correctly the old templates had the code for tables and table cells already filled, these new templates just extend the class and do not include the skeletton.

Answer (score 0):

For 'apple' templates
Developer/Library/Xcode/Project Templates
Developer/Library/Xcode/File Templates

For personal templates
Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Project Templates
Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/File Templates

Comment: I don't think he was asking where the actual templates were stored, just what had happened to them.

Answer (score 0):

OK. Figured out what's up. I wasn't overwriting my old files when i created my files. The templates are indeed in the dropdown. Thanks Simon